# Selenium (python) to select an item in dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, selenium

I am trying to use Selenium in python to select an item "Custom date" in the following dropdown menu:
[image]

This is how the structure of divs looks like:
[image]

I try to first select the topmost div with Selenium (python) and then progress down by clicking all the way to "Custom date" (see code below). However, I get the following error in the last line of code when I try to do that:

`"ElementNotInteractableException: Message: element not interactable"`

My attempt to click the desired field:

```
time.sleep(2)
element=chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Inputreact__StyledContainer-sc-3dr67n-0 iAeYiQ Selectreact__SelectInput-sc-1shssly-0 cJLIjY' ]")
element.click()
chrome.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
element=chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='7 days']")
chrome.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
element=chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Custom date']")
chrome.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

EDIT:
I want to provide a bit more detail. In the case of user MANUALLY using the dropdown menu, the behavior below happens (note what the relevant divs are in the picture). I am stumped because selenium clicking on the div that ends in ePfTsZ ***DOES NOT EXPAND*** the dropdown menu, as happens when user manually does it in the browser.

[image]

Comment: When I manually click in the browser on the dropdown menu to expand it, the aria-expanded value changes from false to true. However, from whatever reason after the first click in my code takes place, selenium does not seem to get access to the "Custom date" menu field.

Comment: What website is it on?

Comment: Also to go through a div dropdown all you need to do is click the top div once and then your value you want otherwise you will the dropdown will close.

Comment: Thanks, however, I just tried to implement your sugestion (click on top div once and then your value) using code below and I got the same error:

Comment: chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='Blockreact__Block-sc-1xf18x6-0 ePfTsZ' ]").click()
time.sleep(2)
element=chrome.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@value='Custom date']")
chrome.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)

Comment: readonly value try removing it first using execute_script.

Comment: Hi, what do you mean "try removing it?" I am not coding the website from scratch-- I am trying to access an item from existing site. Also, I have edited the question to show what div gets highlighted when user presses relevant menu (see new picture attached at the end of question)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240341/discussion-between-user3438258-and-arundeep-chohan).

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use the Select class, will look something like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select

selection = Select(chrome.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//div[@class='Inputreact__StyledContainer-sc-3dr67n-0 iAeYiQ Selectreact__SelectInput-sc-1shssly-0 cJLIjY' ]"))
```

After this you can select any item of the dropdown by index or by visible text.

```
selection.select_by_index(1)
```

or

```
selection.select_by_visible_text("A month")
```

Comment: Thank you. However, I just tried to do this and got the following error: UnexpectedTagNameException: Message: Select only works on <select> elements, not on <div>

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go through all the option of the dropdown, then run a loop on index.

Comment: Can you kindly expand on this? For example, how would I go through all the options and then run a loop on index?

Comment: The attribute `area-invalid` has boolean value. You can see its full properties only when you click it. And selenium works only on visible properties. (Didn't notice the value earlier). In this case, you can use `pyautogui`. Use the api to interact with you browser UI.